# grep all strings that start with a certain char, and finish with another char

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, sed, grep

I need to grep all strings that start with "[" and finish with a certain string, e.g. "apal". So all chars in between these 2 chars would be shown as well. Given an input such as:

```
[44060]apal223reaea[55000]opoer4nr4on[95749]assad fdfdf Bhassrj sdaapald33qdq3d3da3ded[66000]dsfsldfsfldkj[77000]porpo4o4o3j3mlkfxxxx[101335]KaMMMM MMM lapa[131322]sadasds ddd apaladsdas[138133]sadasdadasddsss KMMapaldsadsadwe[150000]idhoqijdoiwjodwiejdw
```

The output would be something lie

```
[44060]apal
[95749]assad fdfdf Bhassrj sdaapal
[101335]KaMMMM MMM lapal
[131322]sadasds ddd apal
[138133]sadasdadasddsss KMMapal
```

Comment: Would you please. post a sample of your in file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
grep -o '\[.*apal' file.txt
```

Replace `file.txt` with the actual filename.

On the other hand, if you want to match `[` at the start of the line:

```
grep -o '^\[.*apal' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am on a MacOS. For me, this command still prints the whole line where the string is - and since this is a huge file with line breaks I can't read the output then. Is it possible just to print the specific matched string (and the chars in between)?

Comment: This would imply, if you used the command line as shown exactly by heemayl, that MacOS silently ignores the "-o" switch.  If so you'll have to consider another tool which can do parentheses excerpted printing (awk or perl).  However at least consider the merits of piping your output to "more" if you're suffering "huge file ...can't read..output".  That is, above then:  | more

Comment: @testTester, I'm on a Mac as well and can confirm that this command works as indicated.  However, **please [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/277089/edit)** to provide a sample input file; if you have multiple pairs of brackets on a given line you will need to tweak the regex involved.

Comment: @Wildcard - I can't provide the sample input file unfortunately, as it is not a public file -  but I will edit the above and make it clearer. The file is round 50MBs, no "\n"s on the file anywhere. I ended up achieving what I need by using `grep -o -P '.{0,45}apal.{0}' ` which prints the match, plus 45 chars before it, which in general ends up covering the the first "[" needed. The output then presents a result per line. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
grep -o '^\[.*apal$' file.txt
```

The command to match a regex: .......use `grep`
To match **only** the regex written, ........use `-o`
To match the start of a line, .................use `^`: `^\[`
To match any characters in between, .use `.`: `.*`
To match the end of a line, ...................use `$`: `apal$`
A file that contains what you want to match.: file.txt

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using grep, you'd do better to use sed.

```
sed 's/.*\(X.*Y\)/\1/p' < file.txt
```

Replace X with the starting pattern, and Y with the ending pattern. This command places into sed's buffer 1 everything that matches X to Y. The "\1" in the replacement pattern will print that buffer.

So, in your example:

```
sed 's/.*\(\[.*apal\)/\1/p' < file.txt
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Nice, but you should add a `-n` flag.

Comment: Yes, it requires the -n flag indeed... otherwise, the sed expression won't work!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the text in between `[` and `apal`, perl is a good choice

```
perl -lne '/(?<=\[)(.+?)(?=apal)/ and print $1' file
```

If you have GNU grep installed (via homebrew for example), you can

```
grep -Po '(?<=\[).+?(?=apal)' file
```

Comment: The `grep` option worked for me (Debian 9). However `perl` only took the first instance on each line.